# Agrupar por un campo y que se vean todos los valores de cada registro - SQL

Tags: sql, nodejs, postgresql, sequelize.js

Necesito agrupar por fecha una tabla con varias fechas con un valor determinado para cada fecha. Por ejemplo:

```
01/01/2016 10
01/01/2016 20
01/01/2016 30
02/01/2016 40
02/01/2016 50
...
```

El resultado debería ser:

```
01/01/2016 10 20 30
02/01/2016 40 50
```

Esto lo he de conseguir en una tabla *PostgreSQL* que manejo con *Sequelize* y *NodeJS*.

```
    var options = {
    where: {mes: req.body.resumen.mes, any: req.body.resumen.any},
    group: 'dia',
    order: [
        ['fecha', 'ASC']
    ]
};
models.Lectura.findAll(options).then(function(lecturas) {
    res.render('lecturas/resumen', {lecturas: lecturas,  errors: []});
}).catch(function(error){next(error)});
```

Cuando iterio sobre lecturas, solo me da la última de cada grupo, algo así:

```
01/01/2016 30
02/01/2016 50
```

¿Cómo lo podría solucionar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No sé nada de node.js y sequelize.js, así que no te puedo ayudar por ese lado.

Pero sí te puedo dejar un modelo de la clase de consulta SQL en PostgreSQL que te permite agrupar los registros de esa forma. Y luego puedes ajustar la consulta según tu necesidad.

Asumiendo una tabla `tbl` con la estructura y datos siguientes:

```
create table tbl (
  fecha date not null,
  valor int not null
);

insert into tbl (fecha, valor)
values
('2016-01-01', 10),
('2016-01-01', 20),
('2016-01-01', 30),
('2016-02-01', 40),
('2016-02-01', 50);
```

La consulta siguiente, usando la función [`string_agg`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html) devuelve los resultados como los pides:

```
select fecha, string_agg(valor::text, ' ' order by valor)
  from tbl
 group by fecha;
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://rextester.com/TTUHB35745)</kbd>

Comment: todo está hecho hasta donde el select, me falta saber qué función  de Sequelize usar en vez de string_agg.

Comment: ¿Hay posibilidad de pasar esa consulta a SQL solamente sin la parte de PostgreSQL y que tenga exactamente el mismo efecto que la Demo?

Answer (score 0):

Este es el código nodejs para resolverlo con Sequelize:

```
var options = {

        where: {mes: req.body.resumen.mes, any: req.body.resumen.any},

        include: [{model: models.Lectura, order: 'codigo'}],

        order: [
            ['fecha', 'ASC']
        ]

    };

    models.Parte.findAll(options).then(function(partes) {

        res.render('partes/resumen', {partes: partes, errors: []});

    }).catch(function(error){next(error)});
```

En options se seleccionan los registros de la tabla Parte que cumplen con la condición de mes y año, y se incluyen sus detalles de la tabla Lectura. Después basta con iterar sobre cada registro maestro y sus detalles.